# Xamarin.forms lifecycle methods using MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can i use app lifecycle methods(or lifecycle methods of an individual page) if my application is structured using MVVM?(is there any  way to do this without mvvm cross or other frameworks?) I ran past this problem when i tried to implement a token auth on my app and i wanted to check if the token is valid before the menu opens.

Comment: what specifically are you trying to do?  As written your question is very broad and impossible to answer.

Comment: Like use a page specific OnAppearing or OnDissapearing methods from the viewmodel. I'm thinking about a behavior that capture an event raised from those methods and let me bind a command to those events?

Comment: create a base page class that automatically calls the VM methods when the page events fire.  That is essentially what any of the frameworks are doing.

Comment: Ty man. I will do this.